# Systemd restart service if one of the processes in the control group fails

Tags: bash, systemd, services, fork

I have a systemd service unit:

```
[Unit]
After=network.target

[Service]
User=<user>
Type=forking
ExecStart=/opt/app/start.sh
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The /opt/app/start.sh starts several processes and forks them:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do
    bash another_script.sh &
done
```

All of the things works fine, until one of the `bash another_script.sh` processes exits with non zero status. I expect that systemd service should restart in this situation. 
Is there any way to watch control-group failures and restart service if this happens?

Comment: `systemd` does nothing because your script - `start.sh` - has not failed.

Answer (score 2):

## Control groups are not jobs.

There is no such thing as a "control group failure".  Control groups are just collections used for resource limiting.  They do not "fail".

What failure that there is here, is a failure to design a service properly.  If one has multiple dæmon processes to monitor, and one wants the service manager to restart them individually if they terminate, then one should be defining multiple services.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). *[Linux control groups are not jobs](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/linux-control-groups-are-not-jobs.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). "[If you have two services, define two services.](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/systemd-house-of-horror/two-services.html)".  *The `systemd` House of Horror*.  Frequently Given Answers.

Answer (score 1):

From `help wait`:

> If the -n option is supplied, waits for the next job to terminate and
>       returns its exit status.

So you should be able to use `wait -n` in your script to know when any of the jobs have finished.