# systemd: restart service if any of the forked processes are killed

Tags: systemd, process, services

Is there any way of auto-restart a systemd service if any of its forked processes are killed?

After creating a systemd unit file for Control-M

```
[Unit]

After       = network-online.target
After       = remote-fs.target
Description = Control-M agent
Wants       = network-online.target

[Service]

ExecStart   = /opt/ctmagent/ctm/scripts/start-ag -u ctmagent -p ALL
ExecStop    = /opt/ctmagent/ctm/scripts/shut-ag -u ctmagent -p ALL
Restart     = always
RestartSec  = 5
TimeoutSec  = 5min
Type        = forking

[Install]

WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

I noticed that it forks 3 different processes

```
# systemctl status ctmag.service

CGroup: /system.slice/ctmag.service
   ├─129041 /opt/ctmagent/ctm/exe/p_ctmag
   ├─129089 /opt/ctmagent/ctm/exe/p_ctmat
   └─129091 /opt/ctmagent/ctm/exe/p_ctmatw -ATW_NAME ATW000
```

If i kill `p_ctmag`, systemd restarts everything, however, if i kill `p_ctmat` it desn't

Or, since `p_ctmat` opens `127.0.0.1:7035` , can systemd monitor this port and restart the service if closed?

---

PS1: I do **not** have control over `start-ag` and `shut-ag`, so [Systemd restart service if one of the processes in the control group fails](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/352026/systemd-restart-service-if-one-of-the-processes-in-the-control-group-fails) won't help here.

PS2: Also, I can't add another script 'layer', wrapping the script in another one. Need pure systemd unit file solution.

Comment: Could you explain a bit why you cannot use a helper/wrapper script? That probably rules out most of the obvious solutions.

Comment: Note that start-ag and shut-ag are vendor-provided wrapper scripts *already*. The start-ag script (among a million other things) eventually calls `nohup some/binary &` for the various processes.

Comment: When I kill p_ctmat here, the AG process restarts it (`.../dailylog/daily_ctmag_*.log` contains "WATCHDOG OF PROCESS AG STARTED THE PROCESS AT"). Does that *not* happen for you?

Comment: The version 9 doco says `rc.agent_user start` and `rc.agent_user stop`.   It's still an unnecessary wrapper script, though.  (-:

Comment: @RASG what I mean is that *systemd* did *not* restart the process for me; CTM itself did.

Comment: Side note: [BMC is stil getting used to the idea of systemd](https://communities.bmc.com/thread/149032?start=0&tstart=0).

Comment: @JeffSchaller CTM does not restart `p_ctmat`.

Comment: @JdeBP should i drop `start-ag` and use `rc.agent_user` instead? would i get different results?

Comment: This is possibly a tangent, but if it's helpful, it appears that I have `WATCHDOG_ENABLED ... Y` in $CTMDIR/data/CONFIG.dat, which may explain the watchdog/restarting behavior that I'm seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trouble you're running into is that BMC has not yet built a native systemd service file for Control-M/Agent. The [installation guide for version 9.0.18.200)](http://documents.bmc.com/supportu/documents/95/15/509515/509515.pdf) (login required), for systemd-systems directs you to use a service file with this template:

```
[Unit]
Description=Control-M Agent

[Service]
Type=forking
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=[agent_home_dir]/ctm/scripts/rc.agent_user start
ExecStop=[agent_home_dir]/ctm/scripts/rc.agent_user stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

... where the Exec lines are just wrappers around `start-ag` and `shut-ag`, which is what you're using. The trouble boils down to systemd being told that this is a `forking` Type of service, when in fact the "service" (start script) starts multiple processes. systemd considers the (forking) service to be successful when it sees the first child process after the initial script. That process ends up being `p_ctmag`, as you've seen. The `systemctl status` output makes it clear:

> ```
> Process: 6519 ExecStart=/opt/ctmagent/ctm/scripts/start-ag -u ctmagent -p ALL (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
> ```

... where pid 6519 was the `start-ag` script, which has since exited. This is followed by the remaining control-group processes you see.

I'd additionally point out here that the [systemd docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) say:

> If this setting is used, it is recommended to also use the PIDFile= option, so that systemd can reliably identify the main process of the service.

... which the suggested BMC service file does not include, **despite there being** PID files for all three processes under `$CONTROLM/pid/`; though they're not *real* PID files, since the files are *named* for the pid instead of the pid being their contents.

This is why systemd is not restarting the `p_ctmat` process.

Short of rewriting a thousand-plus line vendor script to split the processes into individually-controlled ones (complete with the two handfuls of environment variables those scripts set) or waiting for BMC to provide a useful systemd script, my suggestion would be to change your agent configuration to set the `WATCHDOG_ENABLED` parameter to `Y`. In my testing, this enables the `p_ctmag` process to watch the `p_ctmat` process, which will restart it if necessary. The `p_ctmatw` process is a child of the `p_ctmat` process, which will restart `p_ctmatw` as needed.

From there, you're covered:

- `p_ctmag` will be restarted by `systemd`, as now
- `p_ctmat` will be restarted by `p_ctmag` (with `WATCHDOG_ENABLED Y`)
- `p_ctmatw` will be restarted by `p_ctmat`, as now

Comment: Be sure to skip the first and third instructions in that document for "Control-M/Agent automatic startup procedures", as they both point you towards the SysV init.d structure.

Comment: you nailed it. `WATCHDOG_ENABLED` was the culprit.